# How to count number checkboxes ticked in jquery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a table that displays a list of names from a table using a php while loop and next to each of those names is a checkbox so that the user can select 2 names to display side by side on the next page.

I am using a jquery form validator and I would like it to display a message if more or less than 2 names are selected before moving on to the next page.  The validation works well for simple things like straight forward string comparisons etc but I can't getting working with this, I suspect it's because of the way I am trying to get the number of checkboxes that are checked.

This is the form...

```
 <form method="post" onsubmit="return validation()" action="merge_accounts.php"
       name="merge_form" id="merge_form" >
   <table>
       <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
                $account_id = $row['id']; ?>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="merge[]" name="merge[]"  value="<? echo $row['id']; ?>" style="margin-left:10px" /></td>
                <td class="results_cell" style="padding-left:0px">
                    <a title="<? $row['name']; ?>" href="account_info.php?id=<? echo $account_id; ?>" onClick="this.document.id.submit();"><? 
                    if(strlen($row['name']) > 45){
                        echo substr($row['name'], 0, 45).'...'; 
                    } else {
                        echo $row['name'];
                    }?></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" class="no_hover">
                  <input type="submit" class="advanced_buttons"
                   style="margin: 0px 5px 3px 10px; height:30px; width:60px" 
                   name="merge_submit" value="Merge" />
               </td>
           </tr>
      </table>
 </form>
```

The jquery...

```
<script>

    function validation()
    {
        var num = document.forms["merge_form"]["merge"].length;
            if(num != 2)
            {
                $.msgbox("Please select 2 items", {type:"info",
                    buttons: [
                        {type: "submit", value: "OK"}
                    ]
                });
                return false;
            }
    }

</script>
```

At the moment the form just ignores the validation function and submits regardless of how many checkboxes are ticked

Comment: Ah please `java !== javascript` !

Comment: @HamZa, comment !== constructive comment

Comment: @tatty27, actually, yes, it's a very constructive comment, if it drives home the fact that Java and JavaScript are two completely different and unrelated languages, a point you seemed not to grasp when you tagged this as a `java` post despite the complete absence of any Java.

Comment: @HamZa It was an accident, I hadn't realised that I had done it so it may have been more constructive to to point out it had been tagged Java, maybe then I would have known what your comment was in reference to.

Comment: @tatty27 I hate it when people don't differentiate between java and javascript. They are completely different languages for different purposes. I'm allergic to that, that's all. You may have made a "mistake", but I've seen people who didn't even know the difference. Also you could easily check the edit log to see what I was referring to.

Comment: @HamZa, I didn't notice you had made an edit, I just saw a comment about java not being javascript and assumed you were criticising my code.  I too hate it when people don't differentiate between java and javascript but it is worse when people make cryptic comments.  I would think it was quite obvious from the code I had written that I know enough about it to know that the two languages are different and that I had made a "mistake".

Comment: @tatty27 it wasn't cryptic at all, but can't be helped if you thought you tagged it as js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it:

```
$("#merge_form input:checked").length
```

Comment: Do bear in mind that `:checked` is equivalent to `*:checked` (which means jQuery/`document.querySelectorAll()` is looking through *every* element within `#merge` to see if it's checked or not; the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) explicitly advise to specify the tag-name, or other identifier, to the selector in this case).

Comment: @DavidThomas: Thanks for info. I learnt new thing today

Comment: (I should have been more clear, but you'd need: `#merg input:checked`, otherwise you're looking for `:checked` elements within `#merge` that's within an `input`, which will return no elements, since an `input` is a void/empty element by definition. jQuery selectors follow the same rules as CSS selectors, after all.)

Answer (score 7):

To find the number of checked check-boxes:

```
var checked = $('#merge_form input[type=checkbox]:checked').length;
```

References:

- [Attribute-equals `[attribute="value"]` selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector).
- [`:checked` selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector).